# Access session in class library.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing an application architecture that uses 2 sub projects: 
   a) asp.net web application (it covers user interface and business logic)  and 
   b) class library.    (it covers data access layer)

After system user successfully logs in , the user information is stored in a session object.

The problem I am facing is when I try to access that session object in class library project(data access layer), it always returns null.

I need to access the session object in class library project because, in my case each user has their own username and password for database access(for security reasons);

So, How how do i read and write from/to session object in class library project

Comment: You simply can't, Only way to do this is to call specific methods of class library through web project and pass values of session into that methods.

Comment: If this app has many users I would reconsider having database login for each user. You disable connection pooling this way.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem, did you find any solution, Bikash?

Answer (score 11):

Use the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` object.

Comment: it only gives reference to the session object. the sesion object value is always null

Comment: You dont get current session value from here. U only get a reference only

Answer (score 5):

First of all, as Peri correctly noticed - you need to think again if having separate database logins for each user is a good idea - because you loose connection pooling (different users won't be able to reuse existing connections - and creating a new sql connection is quite expensive).

If you really wish to keep separate database users, I would create interface to abstract session from data access:

```
public interface ILoginDataService
{
   LoginData Current { get; }
}
```

And implementation would pass login data from session. In such way you won't have session dependency to session in your data access logic - so it will be more testable, also you'll separate concerns.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like that, because i have i multiclient database in wich every table has a ClientID, so every query i make has to filter by ClientID. How can i use this interface in a way i don't have to pass it in every method call?

Comment: Usually dependency injection container is used for this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code I used within a library to get session information.

```
public static string Entity()
{
    string entity = "";
    HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    if (httpContext.ApplicationInstance.Session.Count > 0)
        entity = httpContext.ApplicationInstance.Session["EntityCode"].ToString();

    return entity;
}
```

Comment: It always shows "Session state is not available in this context."

Answer (score 0):

I am having an ASP.Net application which uses session. I am able to access it in my app_code files using [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] for the function. I am not sure whether this is your problem. I also faced session value as null when I removed (EnableSession = true) on the method.

Answer (score 0):

```js
using System.Web;

namespace ClassNameSpace
{
    public class Class1 : IRequiresSessionState
    {
            private string sessionValue => HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionKey"].ToString();
    }
}
```