# How to use HTTPContext.Current.Session[].ToString to pass connection string to DB Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, session, asp.net-mvc-5, dbcontext

I am trying to pass connection string to my DB Context and it worked when I pass a static variable to it. But my requirement is to pass the connection string in session variable. How can I do that.

Below is the code and the different options I have used

DB Context

```
public EntEventServices_2_0Entities(string strConnectionString)
        : base(strConnectionString)
    {
    }
```

Initiating db object, this worked since it used static variable:

```
private EntEventServices_2_0Entities db = new EntEventServices_2_0Entities(ConnectionManager.strConnectionString);
```

But now since I have saved the connectionstring in session variable therefore I am trying to this:

```
private EntEventServices_2_0Entities db = new EntEventServices_2_0Entities(Session["ConnectionString"].ToString());
```

and this:

```
private EntEventServices_2_0Entities db = new EntEventServices_2_0Entities(HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionString"].ToString());
```

But everytime I am getting following error:

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Mvc.Controller.HttpContext.get'

A bit detail about my application: I am developing an MVC5 application using EF6 and the requirement is to have one application connect to multiple databases of similar model.

Let me know if more details are required.

Comment: how and where are you storing the `ConnectionString` in session , it appears that you don't.

Comment: This link may help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11931004/1107638)

Comment: @Habib I am setting [ConnectionString] in a separate method. `public void ChangeConnection(string strConnectionString)
        {
            Session["ConnectionString"] = strConnectionString;
        }`

Comment: Have you tired to use the fully qualified reference? `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ConnectionString"].ToString()`

Comment: @Yorro, Yes and same error.