# How to get session details using session id in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, signalr, session-cookies

I want to access user session values outside of the controller where `HttpContext` is null. Can we read data from the session even when `HttpContext` is null if we know the session ID?

Tried to create a singleton class and set the values but its not solving our purpose.

Suppose I have UI project which is of ASP.NET MVC type. There I have a SignalR handler. I want access some data which is stored in session when I get a message at SignalR handler.

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930829/access-session-in-class-library?

Comment: The session is a part of HttpContext, if it is null you can not read, even if you know the session id.

Comment: @Muhammad Hannan - ApplicationInstance value is also null

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
Session.Add("Name", Name of item you need); while login and you can access it in any page by 
Session["Name"].